# Explicitly define order of Terraform destroy operations (several providers) when destroying stack

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform configuration that looks like this:

1. With provider `aws`, create an RDS database
2. With provider `https://github.com/cyrilgdn/terraform-provider-postgresql`, create Postgresql databases etc.

The latter is done via separate custom module.

Now, when calling `terraform destroy` I ended up in state where cluster is removed but databases are not deleted, and TF complains with error

`Error: error detecting capabilities: error PostgreSQL version: dial tcp: lookup [host].eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com on [IP]:53: no such host`

which clearly suggests database entities were not removed prior to removing the cluster.

I would like to identify to Terraform that database entities must be removed before cluster itself. How could I do that?

Comment: Does your custom module take details about the RDS database as inputs?

Comment: Yes it does actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [depends_on](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/depends_on.html) meta-argument so `postgreSQL` module depends on `RDS` module.